# Retaining the target url after login

Tags: java, spring, single-sign-on

I am new to Spring framework and trying to implement 'deep linking' i.e. retaining the target URL after login in my Spring based application.
In the simplest terms, it works using 'always-use-default-target' attribute in securityContext.xml.
But whenever a third party authentication is used like SSOCircle and Ping federate, the above changes can't be used.

A bit of documentation dive suggested using 'TargetResource' parameter in the url, but that too redirected back to the default page.
Can anyone suggest if we have any attribute like 'always-use-default-target' in this scenario to have minimal changes.

Any pointer will be really appreciable.

Comment: What you want is the default behavior but if you set `always-use-default-target` to `true` that will not work anymore.

Comment: i am not aware of Spring MVC, but in case of HTTP/HTTPS requests, there is header element `referer`, this will capture the last URL used for coming to current page.

Comment: Sorry for late response, and thanks for the suggestions. Had a work around of using incoming url, as a variable's value, post authentication. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Had a work around of using incoming url, as a variable's value, post authentication.

Comment: Add some more description